# Export XML from MS Access to Import in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, ms-access, import, export

**Background**

I'd like to export multiple data records from MS Access 2016 to XML, which will be further used to import in PowerShell.

I used different native XML-Export Settings (no VBA so far) but all I got is a Array of strings:

```
$path = "c:\MsAccessExport.xml"
$Content = Get-Content $path
$xml = ConvertTo-Xml -InputObject $Content

$xml.Objects.Object.Property
```

[image]

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ($xml.Objects.Object.Property).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

If I check the XML in a XML-Viewer / IE, the export doesen't look that bad, meaning I see the parent (`HolidaySet`) containing a relation to the children (`Holidays`):
[image]

**Question**

- Is there a way in PowerShell to select/Access the nodes as usuall?
- If not, is there a way to modify the Export from Access, to make sure PowerShell can Read it proberly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the XML in this way:

```
[XML]$xml = Get-Content $path
```

Now you can get the nodes value:

```
$xml.dataroot.HolidaySet
```